# Does not clear shared preferences?

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to clear shared_preferences and send the user to a login screen, but seem that the preferences are not cleared? The user ends up on the login screen but next time I run they app they are logged in again as if the preferences are still saved.

```
Future logOutUser(BuildContext context) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.clear();
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Uuurgh... Fixed. Was looking for != "" when doing a check for data, was supposed to be != null.

Noob mistake.